# How can I structure my data to pre-aggregate distinct values over Days/Months/Years in one table?

Tags: sql, powerbi, distinct-values

I have a very large dataset (400mil records per month) which I need to pre-aggregate into a single table before I use the data in Power BI. the aggregated table will run way faster in Power BI, but I need to have drilldown functionality in one visual allowing me to drill down from year to month to day. The problem is, when calculating distinct customers for a day and distinct customers for a month, you should in essence get different figures.

Is it possible to create a single table that can present the distinct customers for each of these time periods in one visual?

I have tried creating a table for each period, one for distinct customers per year, one for month and one for day, but I cannot join these on each other to show them in a single visual.

```
select  event_year,
        event_month,
        Event_day,
        AgeBracket,
        gender,
        race_desc,
        count(distinct ucn) as UniqueCustomers

from bistg.dbo.clickstreammonthsample a

group by 
        event_year,
        event_month,
        event_day,
        AgeBracket,
        gender,
        race_desc
```

Unfortunately it isnt possible to sum, count or aggregate distinct values for a period in any way in order to find a new distinct value over a new period without making use of a cube.

The problem is in order for us to use a cube we need a machine that has 600GB of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you consider two different possible approaches.

First, consider the built-in [Power BI aggregations](https://aka.ms/Aggregations) feature. Though you would use three separate hidden tables, the feature automatically switches between the tables so the same visual can render from the correct table automatically with no additional complexity in DAX. I would recommend this approach if Date is the only dimension you want to slice on.

Second, consider a custom solution I [blogged](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2019/1/4/how-to-make-dax-distinct-counts-100x-faster-with-exact-match-aggs) about which adds day/month/year aggs into a single table and performs some complex DAX and data modeling to automatically display the right aggregation. The solution was designed for Azure Analysis Services (Analysis Services Tabular models) but the same approach works in Power BI. I would recommend this solution if your dashboards allow slicing on the Date dimension, the customer dimension and other dimensions.